# Differences between js objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, prototype

I got the following problem and I am looking for a really efficient way to do this.

I got two Javascript Objects always build like {id:data,id:data,..}

If I only look on the Keys they will look like this:

```
B = ["1","2","3"]
A =     ["2","3","4"]
```

Now I need the information what i need to do, to transform B into A, so in this case: Delete B.1 and B.4 = A.4 .

I was thinking that maybe a prototyp function for Object would be a good way to do this.

This is what i have so far:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
          return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
      };
Object.prototype.syncTo = function(b,callbackA,callbackB){
                var a = this;
                var bKeys = Object.keys(b);
                var aKeys = Object.keys(a);

                var toremove = bKeys.diff(aKeys);
                var toadd = aKeys.diff(bKeys);

                for(var i = 0; i < toremove.length; i++) {
                      if(b.hasOwnProperty(toremove[i])) {
                          delete b[toremove[i]]; 
                      }
                }
                callbackB(b);
                for(var i = 0; i < toadd.length; i++) {

                      if(a.hasOwnProperty(toadd[i])){
                      <<Dont know how to go on now>>    
                      }
                }
                callbackA(XXXXXX);
};
```

Where CallbackA should be called with all elements that have to be added to B and CallbackB should be called with all elements that need to be removed from B.

I am struggling With the elements for callbackA and in general whether this is an efficient way of doing this.

Thank you for your support !

EDIT:
An Example for one of the Callbacks would be :

callbackB:

```
    function (items){ 
      for(var i in items){
         items[i].removeSomeWhereElse(); 
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of libraries that can do this if your search NPM, as a shameless plug I'll just mention one I authored that diffs any object, including array insertion/deletion/moves:

https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch

here's the DEMO page diffing 2 arrays, as you need:

http://benjamine.github.io/jsondiffpatch/demo/index.html?desc=moving%20around&left=%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D&right=%5B10%2C0%2C1%2C7%2C2%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C88%2C9%2C3%5D

you can see deletes, adds, and even moves (move detection can be disabled by configuration if you want)

Using library will be the more efficient in saving your time, now if you want to save CPU cycles instead, you could just use a simple implementation of LCS (which is the standard algorithm to solve to the problem you're describing), see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

jsondiffpatch includes that (for js), and you can steal it from here: https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch/blob/master/src/filters/lcs.js

Comment: I installed the bower version:
 
var delta = jsondiffpatch.diff(obj1, obj2);
console.warn(delta);

with 

var obj1 = {
                a: 1,
                b: 2,
                c: 3,
                d: 4
            };

            var obj2 = {
                b:2,
                c:3,
                d:4,
                e:5
            };

Result is undefiend :(

Comment: @Ludi weird, here's a JSFiddle showing the diff of those same values working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/benjamine/tpgfwuk4/3/